# Vue plugin misbehaving when used with Pug

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, pug, maskedinput

I'm using a Vue plugin [vue-masked-input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-masked-input) for masking some inputs on my site. By default the plugin works fine and as expected, but when running the same code with Pug, I ran into issues.

**Working code:**

```html
<template>
  <masked-input v-model="phone_number"mask="\+\1 (111) 111-1111" placeholder-char="_" placeholder="+1 (555) 555-5555" type="tel" />
</template>
```

[image: Expected result.]

**Doesn't work:**

```html
<template lang="pug">
  masked-input(v-model='phone_number' mask='\+\1 (111) 111-1111' placeholder-char='_' placeholder='+1 (555) 555-5555' type='tel')
</template>
```

[image: Incorrect result.]

I've been using Pug for quite some time now and have never encountered any issue like this. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: What about trying it in HTML? pug do have some weird quirks sometimes. Can you try in HTML?

Comment: that works over there without pug but i have to rewrite the whole component with html and i dont want that

Comment: I've already tried to use Pug before. Had a lot of similar quirks out of nowhere. On top of it, I couldn't benefit from ESlint + Prettier and my colleagues were not really happy with it. I can share you a converter of Pug into HTML in a Vue component if you want. Otherwise, brace yourself for some debugging now and in the future due to the need to escape some chars. Same goes for SASS etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explanation of the problem

The Pug code in your question doesn't result in the same HTML as your "Working code." (At least in vanilla Pug; not sure when using Pug and Vue together, but I would guess that Vue uses the same Pug.)

Most code blocks on [pugjs.org](https://pugjs.org/) are editable (e.g. on the [*Attributes* page](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html)). You can copy-paste your Pug code to one of the editable code blocks there to see the end result:

```html
<!-- Your "Working code" -->
<masked-input
  v-model="phone_number"
  mask="\+\1 (111) 111-1111"
  placeholder-char="_"
  placeholder="+1 (555) 555-5555"
  type="tel"
/>

<!-- The HTML code generated from the Pug code -->
<masked-input
  v-model="phone_number"
  mask="+ (111) 111-1111"
  placeholder-char="_"
  placeholder="+1 (555) 555-5555"
  type="tel"
></masked-input>
```

Differences:

- The `masked-input` tag is not self-closing.
- `\+` is converted to `+`.
- `\1` is converted to `\u0001` ([Unicode control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Control_codes) "Start of Heading").

  - The character is not visible on the code block above, and it's anyway stripped away when editing this answer.
  - The character is shown as a red dot on pugjs.org.

Screenshot from pugjs.org (I used the browser's dev tools to modify the code block on the right to span multiple lines for demonstration purposes):

[image: The invalid Pug code copy-pasted to pugjs.org, showing also the invalid HTML code generated from the Pug code.]

If you copy-paste the `mask` attribute's value from pugjs.org to [vue-masked-input's demo](https://niksmr.github.io/vue-masked-input/) (to the left input under the heading "Your own mask"), you'll get the same result as in your second screenshot. This confirms that the problem is most likely in the incorrect value of the `mask` attribute.

#### The fix

Two changes are needed to the Pug code to fix the HTML:

- Make the `masked-input` self-closing by appending a slash: `masked-input()` → `masked-input()/`.

  - This might not be necessary, but it shouldn't hurt either.
  - See [*Self-Closing Tags* on Pug docs](https://pugjs.org/language/tags.html#self-closing-tags).
- Escape the backslashes with additional backslashes:

  - `\+` → `\\+`
  - `\1` → `\\1`

Like so:

```html
<template lang="pug">
  masked-input(
    v-model='phone_number'
    mask='\\+\\1 (111) 111-1111'
    placeholder-char='_'
    placeholder='+1 (555) 555-5555'
    type='tel'
  )/
</template>
```

You can also put the Pug code on a single line, but placing it on multiple lines improves readability.

Result (identical to your "Working code"):

```html
<masked-input
  v-model="phone_number"
  mask="\+\1 (111) 111-1111"
  placeholder-char="_"
  placeholder="+1 (555) 555-5555"
  type="tel"
/>
```

Comment: never knew this was the problem, thankyou @Matias keep up the good work

Comment: @uneebmeer still, prepare yourself for a lot of debugging like this.